# Pivot MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, database, pivot, transpose

I've been trying pivot a table in MySQL (moving rows to columns). I understand mysql does not have pivot functions so I think a union is required but not 100% sure. I have three columns, user_id, option_id and question_id. I need to group all user_id's and have all the option_ids in one row with question_ids as columns:

I have `SELECT user_id, option_id, question_id FROM table` that gives me the following output:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| user_id  | option_id   | question id  |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| 101      | A1          | Q1           |
| 101      | A5          | Q2           |
| 102      | A2          | Q1           |
| 102      | A7          | Q2           |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I need to have the following output:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| user_id  | Q1          | Q2           |
+----------+-------------+--------------+
| 101      | A1          | A5           |
| 102      | A2          | A7           |
+---------------------------------------+`
```

I've tried using `case` but this only gives me the first row with user_id and I get 'null' for the rest of the columns

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Whats your endpoint here?Since this can be done in another way but it would be good if you explained what does it need to do in the end.And which programming languages will you use to handle this,

Comment: I'm handling this in PHP, the table could essentially have thousands of question_id's and and answer_id's combinations but there will only ever be one combination of user_id and question_id.

Comment: I originally was doing a general select and doing the logic in PHP to organse the table but the impact on my application server was too high for big amounts of data. Seems that if I could figure out a SQL query that achieves this then my DB server could take the hit

Comment: Your problem is that you haven't organized your project well.You would have to structure your database in another way and to rewrite your code in the proper way.Do you have some kind of documentation?Or anything where i could get a better understanding of the project?

Comment: Just to confirm you need the Question form an starting point to a range?So basically you can have Qn?

Comment: I do have a range it would be Q1 - Q150 (but potentially ongoing so Qn) using multiple inner joins on the table seems an inefficient solution so I was hoping there was a mechanism in MySQL that I was unaware of

Comment: Can you put in your question that there are for example Q1 to Q5 and explain it a bit more detailed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147948/discussion-between-arslan-h-and-ross).

Comment: It's a simple enough project, users answer multiple choice questions and these answers are stored in an answers table. What I need is a solution to output all the answers per user in a row. I was doing this in PHP but it's becoming a heavy task on the server, so I was wondering if there was an easier solution in MySQL

Comment: u can use group concat for the same

Comment: Group concat would give me all the column data in one cell though, no?

Answer (score 1):

I had a request to create a flat view of some simple Rain Data.  The data was in a table with just 3 columns (fields) namely 'dDate','mm','comments'.

I needed to transpose/Pivot the data to get it in to a web Table for the user.

This is what I ended up with (As a PROCEDURE) and thought it may help you to structure a query or Procedure to fit your needs.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxxx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_GetYearRainTable`(IN yr 
CHAR(4), IN Tot Char(4))
BEGIN
SELECT 
dDay,
SUM(mJan) AS 'Jan',
SUM(mFeb) AS 'Feb',
SUM(mMar) AS 'Mar',
SUM(mApr) AS 'Apr',
SUM(mMay) AS 'May',
SUM(mJun) AS 'Jun',
SUM(mJul) AS 'Jul',
SUM(mAug) AS 'Aug',
SUM(mSep) AS 'Sep',
SUM(mOct) AS 'Oct',
SUM(mNov) AS 'Nov',
SUM(mDec) AS 'Dec'
FROM
    (SELECT 
    dDay,
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '1' THEN mm END AS 'mJan',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '2' THEN mm END AS 'mFeb',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '3' THEN mm END AS 'mMar',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '4' THEN mm END AS 'mApr',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '5' THEN mm END AS 'mMay',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '6' THEN mm END AS 'mJun',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '7' THEN mm END AS 'mJul',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '8' THEN mm END AS 'mAug',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '9' THEN mm END AS 'mSep',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '10' THEN mm END AS 'mOct',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '11' THEN mm END AS 'mNov',
        CASE WHEN dMnth = '12' THEN mm END AS 'mDec'
FROM
    (SELECT 
    id,
        DAY(dDate) AS dDay,
        MONTH(dDate) AS mnth,
        YEAR(dDate) AS yr,
        mm,
        comments,
        CASE
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '1' THEN '1'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '2' THEN '2'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '3' THEN '3'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '4' THEN '4'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '5' THEN '5'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '6' THEN '6'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '7' THEN '7'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '8' THEN '8'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '9' THEN '9'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '10' THEN '10'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '11' THEN '11'
            WHEN MONTH(dDate) LIKE '12' THEN '12'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS dMnth
FROM
    t_rainData
WHERE
    YEAR(dDate) = yr) tab1
GROUP BY dDay , mJan , mFeb , mMar , mApr , mMay , mJun , mJul , mAug , mSep , mOct , mNov , mDec
ORDER BY dDay) S2
group by
case when Tot = 'Tot' then
   Tot else
   dDay    end
ORDER BY dDay
;
END
```

Incidentally, you will see the use of a tip from this web site (Many Thanks René Nyffenegger and see NB below) that allows me to provide not only the year I want but a parameter which controls the GROUP BY command at the close of the procedure.

NB.  Apparently you cannot support an existing answer to confirm to others that is is valid or usable.  I posted an answer to the reference above and it got immediately deleted.